# How to multiply numbers from two different files?

Tags: python

I have two different files A and B:

```
A= 5 
   2
   3
   4
   6
  78
   ..

B= 3
   4
   2
   1
   8
   7
   ..
```

I need to calculate the multiplication in each file for the two file, I use this code:

```
A_file=open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New_folder\A.txt', 'r')
B_file = open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New_folder\B.txt', 'r')
for a in A_file:
    for line, b in enumerate(B_file):
        #print  b
        print (a,'+',b)
        c= int(a)*int(b)
        print (c)
```

The  result is:

```
('5\n', '+', '3\n')
15
('5\n', '+', '4\n')
20
('5\n', '+', '2\n')
10
('5\n', '+', '1\n')
5
('5\n', '+', '8\n')
40
('5\n', '+', '7')
35
```

But the predicted result is:

```
('5\n', '+', '3\n')
15
('2\n', '+', '4\n')
8
('3\n', '+', '2\n')
6
('4\n', '+', '1\n')
4
('6\n', '+', '8\n')
48
('78\n', '+', '7')
546
```

How to resole this problem please?

Comment: by predicted result, do you mean the result you want?

Comment: if the files are not big, just load them in memory and then do it. Otherwise you need to loop once only. Right now for every row in file A you are doing all rows of file B which is the predicted result based on your code; maybe not the desired one though..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis files are very big, I have more than 200000 line in each file, What I give their is just a simple example  of what I nee to do.

Comment: @JunbangHuang Yes predicted results, are I want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for a, b in zip(A_file, B_file):` to go through the files in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

considering both the file are equal in length

```
A_file=open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New_folder\A.txt', 'r')
B_file = open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New_folder\B.txt', 'r')

alist=[]
blist=[]
for each in A_file:
    alist+=[int(each)]
for each in B_file:
    blist+=[int(each)]

if len(alist)==len(blist):
    for every in alist:
        print (alist[every],'+',blist[every])
        c= alist[every]+blist[every]
        print (c)
```